# Can any 2-variable function be separated?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Can any  function  $f(x,y)$ of 2 variables be written as 
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n(x) h_n(y)$$

If not, what is the condition that allows it to be written as such?

PS: I've read this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59965/separation-of-variables) before.

Comment: what is the difference to the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59965/separation-of-variables)?

Comment: @miracle173 I know that it can't be written as single product of $g(x)h(y)$ but can it be written in series of them?

Comment: what does "written in series" mean? "g(x)h(y)" is a product.

Comment: @miracle173 $Sigma g_n(x) h_n(y)$

Comment: If the function can be expanded in a power series, then the power series is the series you are looking for.

Comment: then you should formulate your question accordingly.

Comment: It's true for a large collection of functions, but only in a certain mode of convergence for the series. See for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105451/orthonormal-basis-for-product-l2-space).